# Overriding parentActivityName from Manifest programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-navigation

Say I have a set of Activities:

1. Activity-A *Parent
2. Activity-B *Parent
3. Activity-C *Child

`Activity-A` is set as `parentActivityName` in manifest for `Activity-C`. How do I programmatically changed the parent of `Activity-C` to `Activity-B`?

I don't quite understand how NavUtils works when it comes to this scenario but i sure don't see any answer related to this.

Comment: What are y9ou trying to accomplish here. Please tell us the problem you have.